# Probability and finding bones

Tags: probability

A dog is searching for bones. The dog digs a hole each time he thinks he's found one. The dog will find a bone or a ball with equal and independent probabilities on each attempt. As soon as the dog finds 8 bones, the dog will go home. However, if the dog is fooled by 8 balls first, the dog will go home. What is the probability that the dog makes exactly 14 attempts before going home?

what I have so far:
so when the dog digs 14 times, that will mean that he has gotten 8 balls or 8 bones (one or the other). But I'm confused on what to do from here.

Comment: If he goes home after $14$ attempts, what is the situation after $13$ attempts?

Comment: he has either 7 bones or 7 balls. which means that if he has 7 bones, he has 6 balls @saulspatz

Comment: That's right.  And then if he has $7$ balls he finds and ball, but if he has $7$ bones he finds another bone.  Can you figure out the probability that he has $7$ ball and $6$ bones?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm having a hard time finding the sample space. can you give a hint?

Comment: @HarrySmith  Forget sample spaces.  Just evaluate the probability for digging up (an arrangement of) $X$ bones and $Y$ balls in $X+Y$ tries.   Hint: What type of distribution would $X$ have on condition that $X+Y$ was a fixed amount (say 13)?

Comment: If $B$ represents a bone and $b$ then we can represent the dog's attempts as a sequence of $B$'s and $b$'s.  How many sequences can we make from $7$ $B$'s and $6$ $b$'s?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I'm confused on what you mean by type of distribution.

Comment: What families of distribution do you know, @HarrySmith ?  Which one described the count of 'successes' among an amount of trials, where each trial is an independent Bernoulli trial (succeed or fail) with identical success rate?  What does its probability measure look like?  Use that.

Comment: @GrahamKemp do you mean $\binom{13}{6}$ x $0.5^{13}(1-0.5)^1$?

Comment: No.  $$\binom{13}{6} 0.5^6(1-0.5)^7$$ (Although it incindentally equals the same value...)

Answer (score 1):

If you assume he either finds a ball or a bone every time he digs a hole you get the following:

- Denote the number of balls he's found by A
- Denote the number of bones he's found by B
- Denote the probability that the finds a ball/bone by p

We must have $A+B=14$. The probability of this is
$P(A+B = 14|\max(A,B)=8) = P(A=8, B=6) + P(A=6, B=8) = p^8\cdot p^6 {14\choose 8} + p^6\cdot p^8 {14\choose 6} =  2\cdot p^{14} {14\choose 6}$

If he always finds either a bone or a ball this means $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and we get 
$P(A+B = 14|\max(A,B)=8) \approx 0.367$.

Answer (score 0):

To go home on exactly 14 attempts, he must find the eighth bone or ball on that attempt.

So either he has dug up *some arrangement* of six bones and seven balls in the first thirteen digs, then found the eighth ball on the fourteenth, OR *some arrangement* of seven bones and six balls in the first thirteen digs and then found the eighth bone on the fourteenth.